# Which language can change class member dynamically in run time?

Tags: c#, ruby, programming-languages, class-design

I know in Ruby can add and modify method of class dynamically in run time. what about other language? what is C# ,can in this language modify or add some method and ... in run time and dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [prototype inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming). A [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming#Languages) of languages is mentioned in the same wikipedia page.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816071/prototype-based-vs-class-based-inheritance) on SO which you can look up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in C# you can add methods at runtime through reflection and the [Emitter object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/3y322t50%28v=vs.100%29).

In C# 4.0 you can even do it in plain C# code with the [Expando object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject). This is arguably closer to the Ruby way (it's practically a carbon copy if I remember correctly) and a lot easier to use.

Edit: All of this applies to all .NET languages, including VB.Net and F#.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of static type systems like C#'s is that all functionality defined for a particular type is known (and checked) at **compile-time**.

If you write

```
foo.jump(42);
```

the *compiler* verifies that whatever type `foo` has, it supports an operation called `jump` taking an integer parameter.

Recently, C# got the possibility of having dynamically checked objects through the `dynamic` type, which basically allows what you described in a very limited context, but nevertheless, the overall language is statically typed.

So what's left are dynamic languages like Ruby, where method existence is just checked at run-time (or call-time).

I think JavaScript can change so called *prototypes* to add methods to objects and basically achive the same thing as Ruby.

Comment: unless you define `foo` as `dynamic` in C# 4

Comment: @M4N: Yes. I consider this a corner case, but edited the answer nevertheless ;)

Answer (score 1):

Python excels at this operation - here are bunch of examples: [Python: changing methods and attributes at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962962/python-changing-methods-and-attributes-at-runtime)

Lisp's object system is also quite dynamic:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System
"CLOS is dynamic, meaning that not only the contents, but also the structure of its objects can be modified at runtime. CLOS supports changing class definitions on-the-fly (even when instances of the class in question already exist) as well as changing the class membership of a given instance through the change-class operator. CLOS also allows one to add, redefine and remove methods at runtime."

Comment: python can't modify the String class

Answer (score 0):

in C# 4 you have dynamic object which you can add/modify at run time.

Comment: That's not entirely true, `dynamic` only means you can (try to) call whatever you want. Actually adding or removing methods is a different part of the DLR.

Comment: Blindy is right: You can add methods to your own objects at runtime, but not other objects.