# Make dictionary function behave like class method

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of methods:

```
def name(self):
   print self.name

def age(self):
   print self.age

display = {
   'name': name,
   'age': age
}
```

And I have a class `Person` where I want `display['name']()` and `display['age']()` to work as methods:

```
class Person:
   def __init__(self):
      self.name = 'Bob'
      self.age = 22
      self.showName = display['name']
      self.showAge = display['age']

person = Person()
```

The problem is that when I call `person.showName()` I get the error

> TypeError: showName() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

How can I make the function `showName` act like a method, and implicitly pass `self` as the first argument?

Comment: possible duplicate of [add method to loaded class/module in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749914/add-method-to-loaded-class-module-in-python)

Comment: Sorry, misread the question - it's not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between a class-method and an instance-method? Is the wording in the title deliberate, or are you confusing something?

Comment: I guess it is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object) instead.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: I'm probably confused with something. :) Python is very new to me. Feel free to edit the title, I'll accept the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy way is to move definitions of your functions outside of `__init__`:

```
>>> class Person:
...     showName = display['name']
...     showAge = display['age']
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.name = 'Bob'
...             self.age = 22
...
>>> Person().showAge()
22
```

Harder way is to understand why does this happens and use `MethodType`:

```
>>> class Person:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.name = 'Bob'
...             self.age = 22
...             self.showName = types.MethodType(display['name'], self)
...             self.showAge = types.MethodType(display['age'], self)
...
>>> Person().showAge()
22
```

In short, a function should be a method to be threaten a bit special while performing `object.attribute` lookup.  This threatening also includes passing of `self` parameter, which your functions expect.  `MethodType` takes function and binds it to some object thus creating a method.

First example works since functions defined along with class definition are threaten as methods automatically.

Comment: Didn't know about methodtype, very nice.

Comment: An alternative to `types.MethodType(display['name'], self)` is `display['name'].__get__(self)`.

Comment: I now have a context problem. The context of `showName` does not contain functions in the context of `Person`.

Comment: @Randomblue you should be able to access all `Person` functions using `self` parameter in `name` or `age` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import partial
class Person:
   def __init__(self):
        self.showName = partial(display['name'], self=self)
```

`partial` allows better support for passing arguments to the encapsulated function than `lambda`, if you'll have any need for more arguments in the future.

Comment: While this works, there is a [better solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
self.showName = lambda : display['name'](self)
```

Comment: This a horrible solution and a very bad misuse of lambdas.

Answer (score -2):

Do this:

```
display['name']()
```

Should work.

Comment: He writes in his question that he already knows this. He wants normal method-call syntax.