# Add method to initialized object (python)

Tags: python, methods, extension-methods

I want to add a method to an object that has already been instantiated.

The object is an instance of type `vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment.SentimentIntensityAnalyzer` (Vader is a popular NLP model).

In order to get the predicted negative tone of a text I need to do the following:

```py
# Import model
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

# Instantiate model
vader = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

# Get negative score
vader.polarity_scores('This text is awful').get('neg')
> 0.5
```

I would like to add a `predict_proba` method such that `vader.predict_proba('This text is awful')` would return `0.5`.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749914/add-method-to-loaded-class-module-in-python) I tried:

```py
# Define function
predict_proba(self, text):
    return self.polarity_scores(text).get('negative')

# Add method to instance
vader.predict_proba = predict_proba

# Attempt
vader.predict_proba('This text is awful')
```

Which throws:

> TypeError: predict_proba() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to activate `__get__` protocol (if you don't know what it is, you probably do want it:), add the method to the class, not the instance.

```
SentimentIntensityAnalyzer.predict_proba = predict_proba
```

You'll also need `del vader.predict_proba` if you're doing it all in one session, to remove the instance function you added, that would override this.

The Pythonic way to do this is to subclass.

```
class MySIA(SentimentIntensityAnalyzer):
    def predict_proba(self, text):
        return self.polarity_scores(text).get('negative')

vader = MySIA()
```