# How to create a class decorator that can add multiple methods to a class, while preserving the IDE's ability to type-hint the methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

**The issue**

I would like to be able to re-use methods by implementing them with a decorator, while preserving my IDE's ability to type-hint the methods added, such that:

```py
@methods(methods=[implement_foo, implement_bar])
class K:
    pass

# OR

@method(methods[Foo, Bar])
class K:
    pass

k = K()

#### THE ISSUE
k. <- #  IDE should recognize the methods .foo() or bar(), but does not.
```

My issue is much like [How to create a class decorator that can add multiple methods to a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232162/how-to-create-a-class-decorator-that-can-add-multiple-methods-to-a-class), but as mentioned, while preserving the type-hint and only use one decorator.

---

**What I have tried**

I can make it work with one decorator, but not with multiple.

Example with one decorator called `implement_method`

```py
def implement_method(cls):

    class Inner(cls):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
            super(Inner, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)
        def method(self):
            pass

    return Inner

@implement_method
class K:
    pass
```

And type hint works for a new instance of `K`:

[image]

I imagine that one of the issues is using a loop, but I am unable to come up with a different solution. The following is my best attempt:

```py
def methods(methods):
    def wrapper(cls):
        for method in methods:
            cls = method(cls)
        return cls
    return wrapper

class Bar:
    def bar(self):
        pass

@methods(methods=[Bar])
class K:
    pass

k = K()
k. # <- not finding bar()
```

Comment: Hi. 

I updated the question. 

I added 2 sections, updated the first paragraph and highlighted the most important code in the first code-snippet. I hope that helps.

Comment: You have to type-hint the *decorator* to indicate what it actually does. It doesn't just return a class, it returns a class that follows a specific *protocol* that you can define. (Also, there's no reason to define a new subclass; just attach the new methods to the incoming class and return it.)

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is a 2 part one:
I have an answer for your first part and I am quite stuck on the second. You can modify signatures of functions using the inspect module, but I have not found anything similar for classes and I am not sure if it is possible. So for my answer I will focus on your first part:

## One decorator for multiple functions:

Let's look at the decorator first:

```py
def add_methods(*methods):
    def wrapper(cls):
        for method in methods:
            setattr(cls, method.__name__, staticmethod(method))
        return cls
    return wrapper
```

We use `*methods` as a parameter so that we can add as many methods as we want as arguments.

Then we define a wrapper for the class and in it iterate over all methods we want to add using `setattr` to add the method to the class. Notice the `staticmethod` wrapping the original method. You can leave this out if you want the methods to receive the argument `self`.

Then we return from the wrapper returning the class and return from the decorator returning the wrapper.

Let's write some simple methods next:

```py
def method_a():
    print("I am a banana!")


def method_b():
    print("I am an apple!")
```

Now we create a simple class using our decorator:

```py
@add_methods(method_a, method_b)
class MyClass:
    def i_was_here_before(self):
        print("Hah!")
```

And finally test it:

```py
my_instance = MyClass()
my_instance.i_was_here_before()
my_instance.method_a()
my_instance.method_b()
```

Our output:

```
Hah!
I am a banana!
I am an apple!
```

### A word of caution

**Ususally it is not advised to change the signature of functions or classes without a good reason (and sometimes even with a good reason).**

### Alternate Solution

Given that you will need to apply the decorator to each class anyway, you could also just use a superclass like this:

```py
class Parent:
    @staticmethod
    def method_a():
        print("I am a banana!")

    @staticmethod
    def method_b():
        print("I am an apple!")


class MyClass(Parent):
    def i_was_here_before(self):
        print("Hah!")


my_instance = MyClass()
my_instance.i_was_here_before()
my_instance.method_a()
my_instance.method_b()
```

Since python supports multiple inheritance this should work better and it also gives you the correct hints.

### Complete working example:

```py
def add_methods(*methods):
    def wrapper(cls):
        for method in methods:
            setattr(cls, method.__name__, staticmethod(method))
        return cls
    return wrapper


def method_a():
    print("I am a banana!")


def method_b():
    print("I am an apple!")


@add_methods(method_a, method_b)
class MyClass:
    def i_was_here_before(self):
        print("Hah!")


my_instance = MyClass()
my_instance.i_was_here_before()
my_instance.method_a()
my_instance.method_b()
```