# How to update an already-declared class during runtime

Tags: python

How can I 'update' a class that has already been declared? My particular scenario is allowing a user to enter code (via a module name) during runtime to update the class when the program determines that the existing class is insufficient. So let's say I have module `ClassA` containing

```
class ClassA:
   def __init__(self, field1):
         self.field1 = field1
```

partway through runtime I notice some cases where I'd like to use `ClassA` if only I could add another field. I alert the user to this and give them the option. What can I prompt them to input? Is it possible for them to give me a filename redeclaring the class? If not, how else would I be able to do this? And if the user does this, what happens to existing instances of the class? I assume they are seamlessly updated if this is done correctly?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what you're trying to achieve? You can certainly add arbitrary attributes to an instance at runtime, but that won't affect other instances of the class (already-created or otherwise).

Comment: An approach like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962962/python-changing-methods-and-attributes-at-runtime#964049 might work. If your code takes care of the rest, the user would only have to provide the function that is to become a method, not a whole class overriding the old one.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically add or replace methods of a class by assigning functions as unbound methods.  For example:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

f = Foo()

def m(self, x):
    self.x = x

Foo.method = m

f.method(123)

print(f.x)
```

This prints `123`.  Even though `method` wasn't added until after `f` was created, it is still callable from `f`.