# Inherit and modify methods from a parent class at run time in Python

Tags: python, class, types, decorator

I have a parent class **of which I don't know the methods a priori**. Its methods can do arbitrary things such as modifying attributes of the class.

Say:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 42
    def arbitrary_name1(self, foo, bar):
        self.a += 1
        return foo + bar
    def arbitrary_name2(self, foo, bar):
        self.a -= 1
        return foo ** 2 + bar
my_parent = Parent()
```

I want to dynamically create a child class where such methods exist but have been modified : for instance say each original methods should now be called twice and return the list of the results from the original parent method being called twice. **Note that methods should modify the instance as the original methods did**.
Aka if I knew the parent class beforehand and its methods I would have done (in a static fashion):

```
class MyChild(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def arbitrary_name1(self, foo, bar):
        list_of_res = []
        for _ in range(2):
            list_of_res.append(super().arbitrary_name1(foo, bar))
        return list_of_res
    def arbitrary_name2(foo, bar):
        list_of_res = []
        for _ in range(2):
            list_of_res.append(super().arbitrary_name2(a))
        return list_of_res
```

Which would have given me the behavior I want:

```
my_child = MyChild()

assert my_child.arbitrary_name1(1, 2) == [3, 3]
assert my_child.a == 44
print("Success!")
```

However you only get a `my_parent` instance, which can have arbitrary methods and you don't know them in advance.
Let's assume further to simplify that you can know the signature of the methods and that they all have the same (one could use `inspect.signature` if it was not the case or `functools.wraps` to catch arguments).
The way I approached the problem was to use `MethodTypes` to bind the old methods to the new methods in various ways and did variations of the following:

```
import re
import types

# Get all methods of parent class dynamically
parent_methods_names = [method_name for method_name in dir(my_parent)
                  if callable(getattr(my_parent, method_name)) and not re.match(r"__.+__", method_name)]


def do_twice(function):
    def wrapped_function(self, foo, bar):
        res = []
        for _ in range(2):
            # Note that self is passed implicitly but can also be passed explicitly
            res.append(function(foo, bar))
        return res
    return wrapped_function



my_dyn_child = Parent()
for method_name in parent_methods_names:
    # following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962962/python-changing-methods-and-attributes-at-runtime
    f = types.MethodType(do_twice(getattr(my_parent, method_name)), my_dyn_child)
    setattr(my_dyn_child, method_name, f) 

assert getattr(my_dyn_child, parent_methods_names[0])(1, 2) == [3, 3]
assert my_dyn_child.a == 44
print("Success!")
```

```
Success!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 52, in <module>
    assert my_dyn_child.a == 44
AssertionError
```

The method seems to work as intended as the first assess passes.

However to my horror `my_dyn_child.a = 42` thus the second assert fails. I imagine it is because the self is not bound properly and thus is not the same but there is some dark magic going on.

Is there a way to accomplish the desired behavior ?

Comment: Is it sufficient for the child class to just hold a reference to the parent class instead of "subclassing" it?

Comment: It would be better if it could be subclassed (see comment)

Comment: This is all a bit hacky, there's probably a better way. What are you actually trying to do at a high level?

Comment: Basically my problem is I get an instance (or a class if it is easier) of which I don't know anything beforehand for instance it is given as an input to a function. From this instance/class I need to (hence dynamically) create a child class that has all the same methods but decorated and with the self correctly bound so that the behavior is exactly the one you would have add if you had used subclassing.

Comment: You could look into using a proxy pattern to control how the dynamic class is called. That would avoid subclassing and probably be cleaner.

Comment: @101 could you expand on what you would do in either a second answer or an edit to your past one ? Using what you told me the way I am doing it now is to 1. create a copy of all methods of parent class with a suffix (it probably is not necessary using super but it works), 2. creating a class binding the original methods to the new ones using MethodTypes (and inside the new methods calling suffixed methods getattr(self, dyn_name + "suffix")()) in the init of the class. This way I can instantiate children using this class with the desired behaviors.

Comment: class MyDynChild(my_parent.__class__):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        for method_name in parent_methods_names:
            setattr(self, method_name + "_orig", getattr(self, method_name))
            f = types.MethodType(do_twice(getattr(self, method_name)), self)
            setattr(self, method_name, f)

Comment: seems to work but I am experiencing some weirdness here and there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually incrementing `self.a` on `my_parent`, so if you ran `assert my_parent.a == 44` it won't raise the assertion error.

I *suppose* this is because `getattr(my_parent, method_name)` gets a method that is *already bound* (to `my_parent`), so future calls to it reference `my_parent` and not `my_dyn_child`.

You should be able to fix it by instead calling

```
f = types.MethodType(do_twice(getattr(my_dyn_child, method_name)), my_dyn_child)
```

This way all method calls are referencing the same `self` (as actual subclassing would do). This works because `my_dyn_child` begins life as an instance of `Parent` anyway, so has the same original methods (at least until we replace them. `wrapped_function` must have a reference to the pre-replaced methods as they are still being called).

All that said, depending on what you're actually trying to achieve it feels like there must be a better way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @101 it does work ! I spent countless hours wo making it work. Do you know if it is possible to do it at the class level ? In order to be able to instantiate several childs using a modified class (and no copy) ?